# Can't update profile "About Me". It says "invalid image" when my image is from the gravatar option

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar, profile-page

Can't update profile "About Me". It says "invalid image" when my image is from the gravatar option. I was given the option to select a gravatar profile picture. Then now when I want to include an "About me" and click save/update/whatever, it says invalid image type.

Comment: What happens what you change to an identicon and save? And if you change it back and save (with an updated "about me")?